# Stack images that use percentage size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how to stack images that use a percentage value to determine size (in this case, 100%) on top of each other.  If they had a set pixel width/height, I would be able to simply adjust their location with position:relative to get them to occupy the same position on the screen.  However, apparently I can't do { position: relative; bottom: 100% } in order to move one under/over the other.

See what I mean with the full browser-width images here:

Warning: lots of large images will download
cmg.reef3.com

I want these all under/over each other so I can reveal them every few seconds with a fade out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use z-order with a fade transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. set `position:absolute` to images. This will make them stacked.
2. Adjust their position with `top:npx;` and/or `left:npx;` and/or `bottom:npx;` attributes (n = number)
3. set `z-index:n` to each image, where n = a number. Higher number will bring the image on top.
4. jQuery-fadeOut the top most image and when fadeOut is finished, it's z-index to the lowest to send it to bottom most.

If you're trying to make a slide show, there are many written scripts available. Something like these

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/top-20-jquery-slideshow-and-image-gallery-tutorials/